# Shorthand for class attributes

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I have the following class:

```
user = User(
    first_name=first_name,
    last_name=last_name,
    email=email,
    age=age,
)
```

I know in JS ES6 you can write this

```
const foo = {x, y, z}
```

instead of:

```
const foo = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    z: z,
}
```

I wonder if Python also has an easy solution to write this shorter without repeating the names everytime.

Comment: You haven't shown your class definition anywhere. Are they all keyword-only arguments?